# While loop decisions based on file reading

Tags: c

I'm running into issues where if I try and close the output file there is an error message and if I don't close the output file nothing displays in the command window nor an output file.
The code is supposed to read integers from an input file and based on the integer it will follow one of two paths. If the integer is <= 0, it will give a print out on the command window and continue down the list. If the integer is >0 it will print out on the command window, print to the output file, and end the loop.
The input file could be any assortment of random numbers, but I have been using these while testing:

```
0
-1
-3
4
5
6
```

The code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
char x;
int seqsum(int start, int end) {
int sum = 0;
int number;
while (start <= end)
    sum += start++;
return sum;
FILE *inFile=fopen("input.txt","r");
while(((x=fgetc(inFile))!=EOF) || (fgetc(inFile) <= 0))
    if (putchar(x) <=0)
    {
        printf("%d is not greater than zero", x);
    }
    else 
    {
       printf("The sum of the numbers 0 to %d is: %d\n", x, seqsum(0, x));
       FILE *outFile=fopen("output.txt", "w");
       fprintf(outFile,"The sum of the numbers 0 to %d is: %d\n", x, seqsum(0, x));
       return 1;
     }
fclose(inFile);
fclose(outFile);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Which character from the input file do you think will have a value `<= 0` ? It is likely to be *only* `EOF` (typically `-1`) but that isn't part of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code upload is kind of garbled. I'm guessing that `seqsum` is missing its closing brace.

The problem is here:

```
while(((x=fgetc(inFile))!=EOF) || (fgetc(inFile) <= 0))
```

But you want x to be an integer read from the file. This is one of the rare jobs for `fscanf`. We use it today.

```
int x; // replaces char x above
while(fscanf(inFile, "%d", &x) == 1)
```

This line makes no sense:

```
if (putchar(x) <=0)
```

It's almost like you want (after the other changes):

```
printf("%d\n", x);
if (x <=0)
```

Also, I'm pretty sure this is supposed to be `"a"` for append as opposed to `"w"` for write.:

```
FILE *outFile=fopen("output.txt", "w");
```

Comment: I found a short amount of code that did some of what I needed I tried to adapt it to my needs. For the FILE *outFile=fopen("output.txt", "w");  why would it be an append? From my understanding the append is just used for when I want to add to what is already on the file and write will write over what is already on the file.

Comment: @walkam: Because otherwise the output file will only contain the result of the last integer in the input file.

Comment: I suppose both could work in this situation, but I only need it to write and not append. I applied your suggested changes and it was only using the last integer until I removed the printf("%d\n", x); The compiler only knew that x=last integer, so the if and else statements were only capable of going off of that value. After some tweaking different lines of code it now works the way that I need it to, thanks for your help.